# python interpreter on USB flashdrive as portable

Tags: python, ide, usb

Can i install python  interpreter on USB flashdrive as  portable to useit anywhere and on any laptop without having to download all the libraries on every laptop or computer?!

I tried to install it in the usb h but it failed

Comment: winpython has a portable version

Comment: What is that and does it contain PIP

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago, I had to build a ["nomad" Python](https://github.com/PhoenixizFire/NomadPython) environnement because of ultra-strict security reasons from a previous company (Bank). Basically it worked like a virtual environnment. The goal is to have in a folder your Python install (binaries, libraries, etc..), which will be made "nomad". (I was able to fetch it via GitHub because it was the only place "unsecured" from the network)

What you can try in your scenario, is using the Python installer, and set the installing Path as your USB drive, as if it was your main drive. Once it's installed in there, you should be able to use it like a normal Python interpretor, as long as it matches the system it's connected to.

If this doesn't work, try building a Python venv directly inside your USB drive.

Good luck !